# close popup in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I am looking to close the pop-up on my parent window using selenium. I am using java.

as of now I am looping through all DIVs on the page until i see "close" text (a button with close text) and then if I find close then click the close button However that takes time as it goes through all DIVs.

Current code:

```
// Find the visible element that has text 'Close' and click on it
WebElement closeButton = Functional
        .getVisibleElement(pDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Close')]")));
if (closeButton != null) {
    closeButton.click();


public static WebElement getVisibleElement(List<WebElement> pListOfElements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pListOfElements.size(); i++) {
        if (pListOfElements.get(i).isDisplayed()) {
            for (int a = 0; a <= ATTEMPT; a++) {
                try {
                    return pListOfElements.get(i);
                } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                    LOGGER.info("attempting to press the element. Amount of attempt: " + ATTEMPT);
                }
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there any way I can just close pop-up in selenium.

Comment: Seems like a javascript popup rather than a new window? If there is only one popup at a time, maybe there is an easier locator to get to it. Can u add the relevant html.

Comment: not a java script window like alert. Its a response from server shown on window.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method if you want to accept the alert popup and pass timeout as needed (example: 4000 (its 4 seconds))

```
    public static void acceptAlertIfAvailable(long timeout) {
    //log.info("Checking if there is a popup alert to accept it");
    long waitForAlert = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
    boolean boolFound = false;
    do {
        try {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            if (alert != null) {
                String alertMsg = alert.getText();
                alert.accept();
                //log.info("Pop-up alert [" + alertMsg + "] was found and accepted");
                boolFound = true;
            }
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
            //log.error("Pop-up alert Not handled and Exception occured --> " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() < waitForAlert) && (!boolFound));
}
```

And if you want to dismiss the alert please try this method:

```
    public static void dismissAlertIfAvailable(long timeout) {
    //log.info("Checking if there is a popup alert to dismiss it");
    long waitForAlert = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
    boolean boolFound = false;
    do {
        try {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            if (alert != null) {
                String alertMsg = alert.getText();
                alert.dismiss();
                //log.info("Pop-up alert [" + alertMsg + "] was found and dismissed");
                boolFound = true;
            }
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
            //log.error("Pop-up alert Not handled and Exception occured --> " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() < waitForAlert) && (!boolFound));
}
```